# Removing cyclic dependencies with a shared event-loop

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, event-loop

I'm trying to resolve a cyclic dependency in the lifetime of a shared event-loop and a shared object that ensures the lifetime of the event-loop.

To make it concrete, here is a stripped version of my code:

```cpp
class TcpConn : public std::enable_shared_from_this<TcpConn> {
  std::shared_ptr<EventLoop> event_loop;

  void send_impl();

 public:
  TcpConn(std::shared_ptr<EventLoop> event_loop) : event_loop{event_loop} {}

  void send() {
    std::weak_ptr<TcpConn> wp = shared_from_this(); 
    event_loop->call_soon([wp]() {
      auto sp = wp.lock();
      if (sp) {
        sp->send_impl();
      }
    });
  }
};
```

The `event_loop` is guaranteed to live for the lifetime of `TcpConn`. The `event_loop` might outlive the `TcpConn`, which makes it a bit more complicated.

To ensure `TcpConn` is alive when the `event_loop` executes `send_impl()`, I'm grabbing a `weak_ptr` to the `TcpConn`, and locking it for the duration of `send_impl()`.

If all other references to `TcpConn` disappear during the call to `send_impl()`, the `event_loop` will be left with the last `shared_ptr` to `TcpConn`. The `event_loop` will then try to destruct `TcpConn`, including, potentially, destructing the last instance of `event_loop`...

`event_loop` destructing itself causes all sorts of issues, especially in my case where `EventLoop` is an abstract base class implemented by the users of my library. Common implementations of the `EventLoop` use a thread, and `event_loop` destructing itself would cause a thread to join on itself.

Is there a pattern I'm missing that will prevent the `event_loop` from having the last remaining `TcpConn`?

Comment: If you ask me TcpConn should be a plain old struct without any functions, all functions should be in EventLoop.

Comment: @HugoMaxwell This is a very stripped down example. The same event loop is used for udp connections, and really anything with a readable file descriptor or anything that needs to ensure that callbacks will not happen concurrently.

Comment: Still I have feeling this problem is self-inflicted and could be avoided by changing the software design. But hard to say without more info.